# Changing firefox tab index

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm working on an addon and I would like to change the index of a tab.
Is it possible to do it in XUL, I Already know how to make it with jetpack but I have to work with XUL.
Any idea ?
thanks

Comment: By index do you mean you want to move a tab from one position to another? Or select a tab?

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely is.

```
const {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

var mostRecentChromeBrowserWin = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
if (mostRecentChromeBrowserWin.gBrowser && mostRecentChromeBrowserWin.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
mostRecentChromeBrowserWin.gBrowser.selectedTab = mostRecentChromeBrowserWin.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[0]; //make the 0 here there number, it starts with 0
}
```